# loadFromJSON() function is loading objects Filled with Pattern only after Click event on the Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

When am trying to `load the JSON data onto the canvas`, every shape is getting loaded but the patterns that are filled in the shapes are loaded only after I click on the shape.

Could some one please explain why this is happening ?
    Even i checked this:

```
canvas2.loadFromJSON(json,canvas2.renderAll.bind(canvas2));
```

Also, the same problem is with the `clone()` function : The Object is duplicated. But the pattern filled in the object is shown only after I click on the object.

Iam using version 1.3.7

Comment: the same problem is posted here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356638/images-are-not-loading-with-loadfromjson-in-fabricjs

Comment: Kindly suggest some solution for this

Comment: No not yet. Did you ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a "temporary" solution, and it works for me in IE9 and google chrome.

My solution is delay the renderAll() of the canvas object right after the loadFromJSON() function is called.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    canvas.renderAll();
}, 1);
```