# Fabric.js - how to give a callback for canvas loaded event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I load my canvas from a JSON object and call `toDataURL` but I need a callback which will be executed after canvas loaded because if there is image on canvas, `toDataURL` function returns a blank page since it's called before image is loaded.

```
 canvas.loadFromJSON(json);

 // I need an event handler here which will be executed after canvas is loaded

 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Read the manual! http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON

Comment: I think this question should be linked to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311448/loadfromjson-function-is-loading-objects-filled-with-pattern-only-after-click

Answer (score 10):

You can use a callback from loadFromJSON(url,callback)

```
<pre>
       canvas.loadFromJSON(url, function () {
            //first render
            canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
            //before call to zoomOut();
            zoomOut();
        });



 function zoomOut() {
         var objects = canvas.getObjects();
         console.debug(objects);
    ......
    }
```

Comment: If the images are from a remote source it looks like fabric doesn't wait for them to be downloaded.

Comment: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/2844#issuecomment-306072572